# Jquery tabs and Google maps problem

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

I have two Tabs in my jquery Application. In that each Tab has a Google Map(version 3).

Map displayed in First tab perfectly. But in second Tab, Part of the map only displayed.

**My Script and Style:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<style type="text/css">

    #map_canvas { height: 100% ;width:100%}
    #map_canvas1 { height:100% ;width:100%}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
        var map1;

      function initialize() 
    {
          var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(11.6952727, 77.5195312);

          var myOptions = {
               zoom: 8,
               center: latlng,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
              };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),myOptions);


    map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"),myOptions1);

     }
</script>
```

**Body:**

```
<BODY  onload="initialize()">

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:100% ; width:100%"></div>  //It is in First tab Div Tag


<div id="map_canvas1" style="height:100% ; width:100%"></div>  //It is in Second tab Div Tag
</body>
```

The First tab Displays map perfectly...But in **Second Tab Part of the Map displayed in corner...**
What is the problem here...please help me...

Comment: can you share the full code (with tabs), so I can replicate, or just give a direct link to jsfiddle. It sounds like a problem with your 100% width/height on hidden elements.

Comment: where's the definition for myOptions1

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forget to define `myoptions1`.

Comment: I have tested it and I see the two maps without problems, but a strange thing happens, because using the same `myOptions`, both maps show the same locations but different zooms...Maybe I am not understanding your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before:

[Google Maps API - Strange Map "Offset" Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647747/google-maps-api-strange-map-offset-behaviour)

> I've seen things similar to this.
>   Without access to any code, my best
>   bet is that the map is initialized at
>   a time when the container div is
>   hidden. I've seen that cause such
>   symptoms. Try to set up your map as
>   you're showing it, rather than before.

The issue is that the 2nd map is hidden while it's initialised and for whatever reason the google maps api doesn't like it. Try to bind the 2nd map setup to the tab switch event AFTER it is shown.