# Call external .js file after an element's CSS property changes

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-events, google-maps-api-2, jquery-tools

I had the same issue as mentioned [here, with an embedded Google Map being offset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647747/google-maps-api-strange-map-offset-behaviour), and not being very Javascript-savvy, I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this in an ideal fashion.

I'm using the jQuery Tools library to make a "wizard" of sorts for my users, as outlined here: http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/wizard.html

One of the panes of the wizard has an embedded Google Map. The map has the problem mentioned in the OP.

To prevent the flash of all the panes of the wizard being initially visible until the jQuery Tools script hides them, I gave the panes the CSS property of "display: none" (except for the first pane). This is the root cause of the issue - commenting out that line in the CSS results in the panes being momentarily visible, and the embedded Google Map working properly.

**My question is simple**: how would I render the following pseudo-jQuery-code in proper jQuery/Javascript?

```
when (.pane.hasMap).css("display") == "block"
{
    load/run external google-maps.js file
}
```

Also, would I need it to run every time the user switches to the pane with the map, or just the first time?

EDIT:

Gah... I just discovered that the Google Maps plugin for my CMS is  automatically inserting the script into the page far above where I had been manually (and redundantly, as it turns out) specifying the script. So, I have no control over when the script is called and the map is rendered.

So, the only alternative I can think of is to have the map's container positioned way off-screen, and then restore it back into place when the tab is called. Something like this perhaps?:

```
if ( $(".pane.hasMap").is(':visible') ) {
    $(".mapContainer").css("top", "0", "left", "0");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do something if something is visible:

```
if ( $(".pane.hasMap").is(':visible') ) {
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/google-maps.js", function () {
          //execute maps here;
    });
}
```

If your using jQuery to show the hidden elements, it's probably better to get the script at the same time as you make those elements visible, like so:

```
$(".pane.hasMap").show('slow', function() {
    $.getScript("https://apis.google.com/js/google-maps.js", function () {
          //execute maps here;
    });
});
```

Comment: D'oh! Just discovered something that prevents this solution from being viable. :( Thanks anyway! OP edited with new info.

Comment: For my own records and in case this helps anyone else: I had the initializing Google Maps script being called in the footer template of every page, but the script was also being automatically inserted before that (this auto-insertion only happened in the page for editing the map in my case/CMS/add-on), so _that_ page had them being called twice, and was breaking. Once I added a conditional statement to not call the scripts in the footer if it was on an Edit Map page, everything seems to work. *le sigh*