# Google Maps API + Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, conflict

I'm trying to load a map generated with Google Maps API on a site. It displays properly inside a normal div but I want to show it only by clicking on a button, and that's the problem: I used jQuery to show and hide the div, but when it shows, almost the entire map is gray:

here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#div').hide();

    $('#button').click(function() {

        $('#div').show();

        return false;
    });
});
```

where's the problem? I appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: You must delay map creation until its container is visible, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064275/how-to-deal-with-google-map-inside-of-a-hidden-div-updated-picture

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - Strange Map "Offset" Behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647747/google-maps-api-strange-map-offset-behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! I solved it by adding this to the map script, in the first few lines:

> function displayMap() {
>
> > document.getElementById('div').style.display="block";
> >
> > initialize();
>
> }

and this to my html:

> `<div id="button" onclick="displayMap()">Show Map</div>`

replace #div with the name of the div which contains the map, and "Show Map" with img, text, whatever you want.